# Angular.js run ng-show function after scope is updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a poll application, in which a user can vote for an option in a given poll. in the html template, i use `ng-show` to show weather the user has voted for this option or this poll or if its an unvoted poll for the user:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="option in poll.poll_options" class="list-group-item">

    <span data-ng-if="option.option_thumb == '2'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
    <span data-ng-if="option.option_thumb == '1'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span>

    <div data-ng-show="optionVoted(option,authentication.user._id)">
            <span data-ng-bind="option.option_text"></span>
    </div>
    <div data-ng-hide="optionVoted(option,authentication.user._id)">
        <div data-ng-show="pollVoted(poll._id,votes)">
            <a data-ng-click="updateVote()">
                <span data-ng-bind="option.option_text"></span> - update
            </a>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-hide="pollVoted(poll._id,votes)">
            <a data-ng-click="createVote(poll,option,authentication.user._id,$index)">
                <span data-ng-bind="option.option_text"></span> - new
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span class="option-votes"> - {{option.votes.length}}</span>

</div>
```

these are the above mentioned functions to determine if the option / poll has been voted by the user:

```
// check if option is voted
    $scope.optionVoted = function(option,userId){
        for (var i = 0; i < option.votes.length; i++){
            if (option.votes[i].user === userId){
                return true;
            }
        }
};

//check if poll is voted
$scope.pollVoted = function(pollId,votes){
    for (var i = 0; i < votes.length; i++){
        if (votes[i].poll === pollId){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the function to create a new vote:

```
// create a vote
$scope.createVote = function(poll,option,userId,index){

    var vote = new Votes({
        user:userId,
        poll:poll._id,
        poll_option:option._id
    });

    vote.poll_option_id = option._id;
    vote.$save(function(vote){
        option.votes.push(vote);
        $scope.$apply();
    }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
    });
 }
```

what happens on the front end, is that the option which has been now voted is updated (not showing an a tag anymore). what i need, is that the other options in the poll will update as well, and now instead of `create()` they will show `update()`, without refreshing the page.

how can I get the other html DOM elements of options in the poll to update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html, replace the functions in ng-show by an object property :

ng-show="option.voted", for example.

and update option.voted in createVote function.

(adapt this with userId etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are pushing the new vote onto the correct object in the scope. It looks like you are displaying data from `$scope.poll.poll_options` in your view, but you are adding to `options.votes` in your `createVote` function.